# Second loop runs once and stops

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, asp-classic

The basic concept behind this code is that whenever it runs, the quantity from an element decreases and the quantity from the same element, but from a different array, increases. For whatever reason, the second while loop only runs once and stops. For example, if `total1 = 11` and `total2 = 0`, the first time the code is executed, `total1 = 10` and `total2 = 1`. However after that, `total1 = 9` and `total2 = 1` and so on. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
<%
count = 0
do while NOT rs3.EOF
    if rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum then 
       qtyArray(count) = qtyArray(count) - qtyreq 
    end if
    if qtyArray(count) >= 0 and rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum then 
       total1 = total1 - qtyreq 
    end if
    count = count + 1
    rs3.MoveNext
loop
rs3.MoveFirst


pickcount = 0
do while NOT rs3.EOF
    if qtyPick(pickcount) >= 0 and rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum then 
        qtyPick(pickcount) = qtyPick(pickcount) + qtyreq
        total2 = total2 + qtyreq 
    end if
    rs3.MoveNext
    pickcount = pickcount + 1
loop
%>
```

Comment: You really don't need to have each line in their own code block like that, it would be much better to have the in a single block. Still trying to figure out your code issue!

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me edit that really quick. EDIT: Done.

Comment: How many records are there in the database?

Comment: You dont need to do "do while" loop twice, you can union two do while blocks into one.

Comment: Usually I would agree. However, in the project I am working on, total1 and total2 are being entered into two different tables. Thus, I have to have the two "do while" loops. I just simplified my code for SO.

Comment: Ok I got your reason. Please make sure you have the right "itemum"  value, because I think the code works but `if qtyPick(pickcount) >= 0 and rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum` returns false so because of that your total2 variable is not incremented.

Comment: I've checked my code and I am sure that the "itemnum" value is correct. However, the problem still remains. If it helps, I should also let you know that I have these two "do while" loops in between <div> and <table> tags. Not sure if that will help, but I will try and give out as much info as I can.

Comment: Just played around with my code a little bit and I noticed that even if I delete `rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum`, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Then that must mean that `qtyPick(pickcount) >= 0` is returning false for whatever reason. See what `qtyPick` values are as you're debugging through it.

Comment: is the cursor capable of a rs3.MoveFirst? some cursor are forward only, so check the values of count and pickcount, are they the same? if not you have a cursor issue...

Comment: I have taken a look at the cursor capability of rs3 and it can use `rs3.MoveFirst`. The values of `count` and `pickcount` are the same so there isn't a problem there. However, upon further inspection, even if I take out `if qtyPick(pickcount) >= 0 and rs3("ITEM_NO") = itemnum then` and the `end if` corresponding to that if statement, total2 won't increment.

Comment: Do you happen to have the forbidden "on error resume next" somewhere in your code?

Did you isolate this code as much as possible?

Comment: No I don't have that in my code and I have isolated this code as much as I can.

Comment: can you tell me the value of "pickcount" after the code executed?

Comment: Sadly, I can't. This code is in an asp file and I'm not sure how to step into the code. The only way that I can try and figure out what is wrong is to open the file into a browser. If you have a way to step into asp code, then would you please let me know?

Comment: write `Response.Write pickcount` after the last `loop` (end of the code) and tell me that this value is what you are expected?

Comment: The value of `pickcount` is 9 and that is what I expected.

Comment: Yes, that means exactly your problem is in the if clause, pickcount=9 means that your "do..while loop" is working as expected. Also, please make sure your "qtyreq" variable is not 0 and really adds +1 to your total2.

Comment: I am a complete IDIOT!!!!! Apparently I kept setting every element in qtyPick as 0 every time I ran the file. That's why it wouldn't increment. /facepalm

Comment: @htbasaran Since you stayed and tried to help me through my idiocy. Please post something and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total2 = total2 + qtyreq
```

Please make sure "qtyreq" variable is not 0 and really adds +1 to your total2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a line on your second loop `pickcount = pickcount + 1`. Just move this line above the  line `rs3.MoveNext` of your second loop